# Help solving this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm starting to study PDEs and i'm having problem solving this one:

$$x^2u_x-xyu_y=2x^3+x^2y+x^2+\frac{x^3y}{x+1}$$
$$u(t,t+1)=t^2+t, t>0$$

What i've done so far:

Using the method of characteristics, we can say (defining $x(s)=\alpha(s)$ and $y(s)=\beta(s)$: $$\alpha'(s)=\alpha^2(s)$$ $$\beta'(s)=-\alpha(s)\beta(s)$$

from this, we have that: $$\alpha(s)=\frac{1}{c_1-s}$$ $$\beta(s)=e^{-s\frac{1}{c_1+s}+c_2}$$
for us to have $\alpha(0)=t$ and $\beta(0)=t+1$ we need to have $c_1=\frac{1}{t}$ and $c_2=ln(t+1)$, then, we have: $$\alpha(s)=\frac{t}{1-ts}$$ $$\beta(s)=e^{-s\frac{t}{1-ts}}(t+1)$$

then (and here is where i'm stucked):

$$u(\alpha(s),\beta(s))=\int_{0}^{s}\frac{d}{ds}u(\alpha(s),\beta(s))ds + u(\alpha(0),\beta(0))$$

$$=\int_{0}^{s}\left[2\left(\frac{t}{1-ts}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{t}{1-ts}\right)^2e^{-s\frac{t}{1-ts}}(t+1) + \left(\frac{t}{1-ts}\right)^2 + \frac{\left(\frac{t}{1-ts}\right)^3e^{-s\frac{t}{1-ts}}(t+1)}{\frac{t}{1-ts}+1} \right]ds + t^2+t$$

The problem is that $$\int_{0}^{s}\frac{\left(\frac{t}{1-ts}\right)^3e^{-s\frac{t}{1-ts}}(t+1)}{\frac{t}{1-ts}+1}ds$$ doesn't seen to have a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2u_x-xyu_y=2x^3+x^2y+x^2+\frac{x^3y}{x+1}$$
Charpit-Lagrange systhem of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{du}{2x^3+x^2y+x^2+\frac{x^3y}{x+1}}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}$ :
$$xy=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving
$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{du}{2x^3+x^2y+x^2+\frac{x^3y}{x+1}}=
\frac{du}{2x^3+x^2\frac{c_1}{x}+x^2+\frac{x^3\frac{c_1}{x}}{x+1}}$

$du=\left(2x+\frac{c_1}{x}+1+\frac{c_1}{x+1}\right)dx$

$u=x^2+x+c_1\ln(x(x+1))+c_2$
$$u-x^2-x-xy\ln(x(x+1))=c_2 $$
The general solution of the PDE on the form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=x^2+x+xy\ln(x(x+1))+F(xy)} $$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the specified condition $\quad u(t,t+1)=t^2+t, t>0$ .
$$t^2+t+t(t+1)\ln(t(t+1))+F(t(t+1))=t^2+t$$
$$F(t(t+1))=-t(t+1)\ln(t(t+1))$$
Let $X=t(t+1)$ with $t>0\quad\implies\quad X>0$ .
$$F(X)=-X\ln(X)$$
The function $F(X)$ is known now. We put it into the above general solution where $X=xy$ :
$$u=x^2+x+xy\ln(x(x+1))-xy\ln(xy)$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=x^2+x+xy\ln(\frac{x+1}{y})} $$

Answer (score 1):

From the equation

\begin{align}
x^{2} u_{x} - xy u_{y} = 2x^{3} + x^{2} y + x^{2} + \frac{x^{3} y}{x + 1}
\end{align}

you have the relations

\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{x^{2}} = \frac{dy}{-x y} = \frac{du}{2x^{3} + x^{2} y + x^{2} + \frac{x^{3} y}{x + 1}}
\end{equation}

From the first equality, we find the characteristic curve

\begin{equation}
xy = C_{1}
\end{equation}

From the first and third ratios, we find

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{x^{2}} &= \frac{du}{2x^{3} + x^{2} y + x^{2} + \frac{x^{3} y}{x + 1}} \\
&= \frac{du}{2x^{3} + C_{1} x + x^{2} + \frac{C x^{2}}{x + 1}} \\
\implies du &= \left( 2x + \frac{C_{1}}{x} + 1 + \frac{C}{x + 1} \right) dx \\
\implies u &= x^{2} + x + C_{1} \ln(x) + C_{1} \ln(x+1) + C_{2}
\end{align}

Using the functional relationship $C_{2} = f(C_{1})$

\begin{equation}
u = x^{2} + x + x y \ln(x) + x y \ln(x + 1) + f(x y)
\end{equation}

which you can check satisfies the PDE. Using $u(t, t+1) = t^{2} + t$, we get

\begin{align}
u(t, t + 1) &= t^{2} + t + t (t + 1) \ln(t) + t (t + 1) \ln(t + 1) + f(t (t + 1)) \\
&= t^{2} + t \\
\implies f(t (t + 1)) &= - t (t + 1) \ln(t (t + 1))
\end{align}

and so we have $f(x y) = - x y \ln(x y)$. Putting it all together

\begin{equation}
u = x^{2} + x + x y \ln(x) + x y \ln(x + 1) - x y \ln(x y)
\end{equation}